# Delete an item unit test in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-core

I have the delete method in asp.net web api.

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
public void Delete(int id)
{
    _repository.DeleteRestrictions(id);
}
```

Not sure how to do an unit test for it. My partial code

```
[Fact]
public void DeleteRestrictionsRepository()
{
    var mockRepository = new Mock<IRepository>();
    var repo = mockRepository.Object;
    var demoItem = GetTestItems();
    var controller = new MyController(repo);
    var result = controller.Delete(2) as OkNegotiatedContentResult<Restrictions>;
    controller.Delete(123);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not returning anything from the controller, so there is very little result you can test.

You can check that the Delete upon the repository was called tho.

```
[Fact]
public void DeleteRestrictionsRepository()
{
    const int DeletedId = 123;
    var mockRepository = new Mock<IRepository>();
    var controller = new MyController(mockRepository.Object);
    controller.Delete(DeletedId);

    mockRepository.Verify(v => v.DeleteRestrictions(DeletedID), Times.Once());
}
```